# Blazor (Server) scoped object in dependency injection creating multiple instances

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

For demonstration purposes let's say I have a class called StateManager:

```
public class StateManager
{
    public StateManager()
    {
        IsRunning = false;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        IsRunning = true;
        KeepSession();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Id = null;
        IsRunning = false;
    }

    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public bool IsRunning { get; private set; }

    private async void KeepSession()
    {
        while(IsRunning)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Id} checking in...");
            await Task.Delay(5000); 
        }
    }
}
```

It has a method that runs after it is initiated that writes it's Id to the console every 5 seconds.

In my Startup class I add it as a Scoped service:

```
services.AddScoped<StateManager>();
```

Maybe I am using the wrong location but in my **MainLayout.razor** file I am initializing it on **OnInitializedAsync()**

```
@inject Models.StateManager StateManager
...
@code{
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        StateManager.Initialize();
    }
}
```

When running the application after it renders the first page the console output is showing that there are 2 instances running:

> bcf76a96-e343-4186-bda8-f7622f18fb27 checking in...
>
> e5c9824b-8c93-45e7-a5c3-6498b19ed647 checking in...

If I run **Dispose()** on the object it ends the **KeepSession()** while loop on one of the instances but the other keeps running. If I run **Initialize()** a new instance appears and every time I run **Initialize()** new instances are generated and they are all writing to the console with their unique id's. I am able to create as many as I want without limit.

I thought injecting a Scoped<> service into the DI guaranteed a single instance of that object per circuit? I also tried initializing within the **OnAfterRender()** override in case the pre-rendering process was creating dual instances (although this does not explain why I can create so many within a page that has the service injected).

Is there something I am not handling properly? Is there a better location to initialize the StateManager aside from MainLayout?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I also tried initializing within the OnAfterRender() override in case the pre-rendering process was creating dual instances

It is caused by pre-rendering & the `StateManager` is not disposed.

But you cannot avoid it by putting the initialization within `OnAfterRender()`. An easy way is to **use the `RenderMode.Server`** instead.

```
<app>
    @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
    @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.Server)) 
</app>
```

Since your `StateManager` requires a knowledge on `StateManagerEx`, let's firstly take a dummy `StateManagerEx` as an example, which is easier than your scenario:

```
public class StateManagerEx
{
    public StateManagerEx()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
    public string Id { get; private set; }
}
```

When you render it in `Layout` in `RenderMode.Server` Mode:

```
<p> @StateManagerEx.Id </p>
```

You'll get the Id only once. However, if you render it in `RenderMode.ServerPrerendered` mode, you'll find that:

1. When browser sends a request to server ( but before Blazor connection has been established), the server pre-renders the App and returns a HTTP response. This is the first time the `StateManagerEx` is created.
2. And then after the `Blazor` connection is established, another `StateManagerEx` is created.

I create a screen recording and increase the duration of each frame by `+100ms`, you can see that its behavior is exactly the same as what we describe above (The Id gets changed):

[image]

The same goes for the `StateManager`. When you render in `ServerPrerendered` mode, there will be two `StateManager`, one is created before the Blazor connection has been established, and the other one resides in the circuit. So you'll see two instances running.

> If I run Initialize() a new instance appears and every time I run Initialize() new instances are generated and they are all writing to the console with their unique id's.

Whenever you run `Initialize()`, a new `Guid` is created. However, the `StateManager` instance keeps the same ( while `StateManager.Id` is changed by `Initialize()`).

> Is there something I am not handling properly?

Your `StateManager` **did not implements the `IDisposable`**. If I change the class as below:

```
public class StateManager : IDisposable
{
    ...
}
```

even if I render the `App` in `ServerPrerendered` mode, there's only one `91238a28-9332-4860-b466-a30f8afa5173 checking in...` per connection at the same time:

[image]

Comment: Thank you itminus - your suggestions led me down the right path. I did indeed need to implement IDisposable in order to properly handle the pre-rendering scenario (was able to keep pre-rendering on). As for the multiple IDs it is now all referencing the same object as expected. You were correct that just the Id had changed.